# Custom shader materials

Tags: glsl, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to get custom shaders working with Forge Viewer.

I've read these posts:

- [Forge Viewer Custom Shaders](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1)
- [Custom shader materials in Forge Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer)

This non-shader material works perfectly fine and renders everything in magenta:

```js
let customMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: new THREE.Color("#FF00FF"),
    name: `not-built-white`,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
});
```

But when I try to make a material with shaders, it gives me this error:

```
[.WebGL-0x11817735400] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Active draw buffers with missing fragment shader outputs.
```

And all of my meshes are invisible (but can still be clicked/selected).

It doesn't seem to matter if it's a ShaderMaterial or a RawShaderMaterial, or what I put in the shaders. I've tried hundreds of variants and Googled my poor little heart out. I tried including all of the #DEFINE stuff for MRIT detection, I've tried setting layout(location = x) to various values, using `gl_FragData`, etc.

Here's my current material setup:

```js
  let VertexShader = `
    attribute vec3 position;
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
    
    void main() {
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    }
  `;

  let FragmentShader = `
    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0); // simply output a solid yellow color
    }
  `;

  let customShaderMaterial = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: VertexShader,
    fragmentShader: FragmentShader,
    name: 'custom-shader-material',
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  });
```

Here's my forge version:

```json
"@types/forge-viewer@^7.5.7":
  version "7.5.7"
  resolved "https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/forge-viewer/-/forge-viewer-7.5.7.tgz"
  dependencies:
    "@types/three" "^0.93.30"
```

What does this error mean, and how do I fix it or even debug it?

Comment: There is an open-source program [ShadeRED](https://shadered.org/) which you can use to debug shaders.

Comment: @thedemons I think that's for desktop apps, not WebGL, no?

Comment: It doesn't attach the debugger to your application, I don't think that is possible, it loads the shaders into its own renderer and debugs them.

Comment: To be clear, my shader compiles and links correctly. The problem is at run-time based on some internal state of Autodesk Forge, which is a proprietary 3rd-party library on top of THREE.js. I'm trying to figure out what buffers are bound in Forge that might cause this, or similar. E.g. this person had the same error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152847/how-to-add-custom-material-to-a-fragment-in-forge-viewer but they were using MeshPhongMaterial, which works for me. I'm just trying to get a ShaderMaterial to work too.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, all I had to do was add this to the material properties:

```js
supportsMrtNormals: true
```

Then put all the #defines from the second blog post back into the top of the fragment shader:

```c
#ifdef _LMVWEBGL2_
      #if defined(MRT_NORMALS)
        layout(location = 1) out vec4 outNormal;
        #if defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
          layout(location = 2) out vec4 outId;
          #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
            layout(location = 3) out vec4 outModelId;
          #endif
        #endif
      #elif defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
        layout(location = 1) out vec4 outId;
        #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
          layout(location = 2) out vec4 outModelId;
        #endif
      #endif
    #else
      #define gl_FragColor gl_FragData[0]
      #if defined(MRT_NORMALS)
        #define outNormal gl_FragData[1]
        #if defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
          #define outId gl_FragData[2]
          #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
            #define outModelId gl_FragData[3]
          #endif
        #endif
      #elif defined(MRT_ID_BUFFER)
        #define outId gl_FragData[1]
        #if defined(MODEL_COLOR)
          #define outModelId gl_FragData[2]
        #endif
      #endif
    #endif
```