# Find elements with opacity==0 elements and make them visible with Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

We're trying to visualize an IFC model with forge that contains a lot of invisible elements.
One problem we're facing is that the elements that is invisible does not fall under the normal category of hidden elements. E.g. `model.setAllVisibility(true)` does not make them appear. Also, `model.visibilityManager.hiddenNodes` is empty and `model.visibilityManager.setVisibilityOnNode(dbId, true)` does nothing to make them appear.

What seems to be the case with these elements is that their `material.opacity` is 0.
We tried setting the opacity to 1, and also tried using a different material, with no luck.
The only thing we have managed to do so far is to highlight the element's corresponding fragment:

```
model.setHighlighted(fragId, true)
```

however, this does not really cut it (unless it's possible to highlight many elements, and make them transparent?).

It's also worth mentioning that:

- The elements comes from a `IfcBuildingElementProxy` IFC type
- Calling `viewer.setDisplayEdges(true)` makes it possible to see the wireframe of the invisible elements
- It's possible to click on the elements even though they are invisible.

So, my questions:

- Is there any good way to find all the invisible elements in a model?
- Is it possible to change them to be visible without highlighting them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The viewer doesn't provide any solution for this out-of-the-box but it should be quite straightforward by putting together some of the viewer's features:

To check the opacity of all objects, you can just get the list of all fragments, and check the opacity of each material:

```js
const frags = viewer.model.getFragmentList();
for (let i = 0; i < frags.getCount(); i++) {
    const mat = frags.getMaterial(i);
    console.log(mat.opacity);
}
```

And then, when you find materials you would like to change, you can do that, too. Here's some resources that might help:

- [how to add custom material to a fragment in forge viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70152847/how-to-add-custom-material-to-a-fragment-in-forge-viewer)
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/material-swatches-forge-viewer
- https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/custom-shader-materials-forge-viewer